# Highlight radio buttons with images inside and

Tags: android, radio-button, customization

I have this RadioGroup:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/disclosure_button" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_de_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/german_flag" 
        android:state_checked="@color/blue"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_en_start"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:button="@null"
          android:checked="true"
          android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/english_flag" 
        android:state_checked="@color/blue"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_tr_start"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:button="@null"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/turkish_flag" 
        android:state_checked="@color/blue"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

I want it to be highlighted when i click one. The original RadioButtons are gone. I already tried it with this selector but it doesn't work...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/blue"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/blue"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

What can i do to highlight each button when it gets clicked in XML and not code behind?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've placed the selector attribute `android:state_checked="true"` inside your layout instead of the drawable. You should remove the attribute from your layout:

`<RadioButton [...]`<s>`android:state_checked="@color/blue"`</s>`/>`

And and a selector state to your drawable resource (here it will display checked items against a red background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/red"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/blue"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/blue"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Note that a checked item's background will remain red even when pressing as the first selector item takes precedence. You may want to consider adding an additional rule for checked and focused/pressed items.

Comment: So i changed my xml file like that and put removed the Android:state_checked="@color/blue". Still no colored background when i click the flags :/

Comment: What do you mean when you write "the original RadioButtons are gone"?

Comment: this here:           android:button="@null"
it removes the round button from the radiobutton^^

Comment: I copied your code verbatim and replaced the background drawable with the snippet above, and it works as expected. Perhaps there's something else that's interfering?